# how to fetch metadata from parquet file using pyarrow

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

The request is to fetch the schema details of a parquet file using pyarrow. The column names could be fetched using the below code. But, unable to fetch other column metadata (data type, null-ability).

```
schema = ParquetDataset.schema
column_count = {"column_count":len(schema.names)}
for index, columnname in enumerate(schema.names,1):
            
                        column_id = str(index)
                        column_name = str(columnname)
```

The code is in python. When the schema is printed, the required fields and data type is available.

```
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x0000015FFFA1B730>
required group field_id=0 org.apache.avro.file.Header {
  optional int64 field_id=1 XXXX;
  optional binary field_id=2 XXXX (String);
  optional int64 field_id=3 XXXX;
  optional binary field_id=4 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=5 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=6 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=7 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=8 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=9 XXXX (String);
  optional binary field_id=10 XXXX (String); 
}
```

Comment: What information do you exactly need from the schema? The `ParquetSchema` has a `columns(..)` method, with which you can access more information (eg the name, type) of a single column.